# Weyl group representation

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a reductive p-adic group.
Let $W$ be a weyl group. if $w$, and $w_o \in W$.
I want to know in which case we have $w w_o w^{-1}= w_o$ ?

in case if $w_o(\theta)=\theta $ where $\theta$ is a subset of simple roots, and $w$ is the longest element in $W_\theta$, the subgroup of $W$ generated by $s_\alpha$ (simple reflection of $\alpha$), where $\alpha$ is in $\theta$.

thanks.

Comment: Please use TeX on this site.

Comment: This guide should help you get started with formatting mathematics at MO and MSE: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/166535